# how to know when to run redis.quit()

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I've been playing around with javascript/node and redis for a while now and I'm struggling to understand callbacks, promises and how to generally work with redis using node. Much fun.

My code:

```
var redis = require('redis')
let client = ''

InitializeRedis()
DoLoop()


function InitializeRedis() {
    client = redis.createClient()

    client.on('ready', () => console.log(Date() + ' - connected'))
    client.on('end', () => console.log(Date() + ' - end'))
}

function DoStuff(val) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        client.sadd('EventList', 'EventID:' + val, (err,res) => {
            if(res == 1) { resolve('Ok') } else { reject('notOk') }
        })

    })
}

function DoLoop() {
    for(let counter = 0; counter <= 10; counter++) {
        DoStuff(counter)
         .then((err) => addEventID(counter).then())
         .catch(err => addEventID(counter))
    }
}

function addEventID(counter) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.hmset('EventID:'+counter, 'field','value', (err, res) => { console.log( err, res); resolve() })
})

}
```

I am trying to determine the next action/call to redis by the first response. if SADD returns 1 then add a new hash and when 0 then do another action. This is something that should be quite straightforward. Probably is .. I'm just missing something :)

When I'm looking at the redis monitor screen I see:

```
1536686206.472510 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "sadd" "EventList" "EventID:0"
1536686206.472571 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "sadd" "EventList" "EventID:1"
1536686206.472603 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "sadd" "EventList" "EventID:2"
1536686206.472635 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "sadd" "EventList" "EventID:3"
1536686206.472672 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "sadd" "EventList" "EventID:4"
1536686206.472678 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "sadd" "EventList" "EventID:5"
1536686206.472707 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "sadd" "EventList" "EventID:6"
1536686206.472736 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "sadd" "EventList" "EventID:7"
1536686206.472745 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "sadd" "EventList" "EventID:8"
1536686206.472770 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "sadd" "EventList" "EventID:9"
1536686206.472796 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "sadd" "EventList" "EventID:10"
1536686206.474576 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "hmset" "EventID:0" "field" "value"
1536686206.474633 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "hmset" "EventID:1" "field" "value"
1536686206.474645 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "hmset" "EventID:2" "field" "value"
1536686206.474651 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "hmset" "EventID:3" "field" "value"
1536686206.474689 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "hmset" "EventID:4" "field" "value"
1536686206.474700 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "hmset" "EventID:5" "field" "value"
1536686206.474735 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "hmset" "EventID:6" "field" "value"
1536686206.474742 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "hmset" "EventID:7" "field" "value"
1536686206.474774 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "hmset" "EventID:8" "field" "value"
1536686206.474782 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "hmset" "EventID:9" "field" "value"
1536686206.474814 [0 127.0.0.1:59218] "hmset" "EventID:10" "field" "value"
```

I am expecting to see SADD -> HMSET -> SADD -> HMSET ..

I don't understand why they are all SADD and all HMSET. That is the first question.. why is it like this?

Second questions and this is a mystery for me.. when to use the client.quit().. when not using it the code hangs forever since it's waiting for new input/query or quit.. and when I quit then HMSET says that the connection has already been terminated.

What is the proper place and method how to use the client.quit() ..

4 days at it now with the callbacks. I think I now understand but.. applying this to node_redis..

Thank you!